# Inverting a graph

Tags: c#, linq, graph-theory

(I hope I used 'inverting' correctly)

I have a collection of nodes (objects) and edges (a list of other objects to which the node refers to). The whole graph is represented in a `Dictionary<string, List<string>`.

(Sidebar: The object in question is not `string` in reality. The actual type of the object is of no consequence)

Now, I need to invert the graph, so rather than having a list of objects and all the objects they refer to, I have a list of objects and all the objects that refer to *them*.

I can do this pretty easily with a loop, but I imagine there's a better way using Linq. Is this the case, and if so, how do I do it?

Just to ensure that we're clear, let's pretend that my dataset looks like this:

```
var graph = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> {
    {"A", new string[] { "C", "D" } },
    {"B", new string[] { "D" } },
    {"C", new string[] { "D" } },
    {"D", new string[] { "B" } }, //note that C and D refer to each other
};
```

I need to transform it into the moral equivalent of this:

```
var graph = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> {
    {"A", new string[] {  } },
    {"B", new string[] { "D" } },
    {"C", new string[] { "A" } },
    {"D", new string[] { "A", "C", "B" } },
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is there no data for "C" in the "moral equivalent" example?  Is not "A" pointing to it in the first dataset.

Comment: @Kirk, That is because I am retarded. I plotted this example out on my whiteboard, but missed an edge! But yes, thanks!

Comment: This would be trivial with just a list of edges.  :)

Comment: @Jeff, Unfortunately, objects are not generally representable in `AB BA` format ;)

Comment: Also, where did Ani's answer go? I was trying to comment that I was okay with not getting empty sets, as in practise, I won't actually have any such data.

Comment: @Mike Caron: He probably deleted it because we all assumed (based on your example) that such empty sets were not okay. :-( His solution is _clearly_ the way to go if that is okay.

Comment: Argh, faulty specs, the bane of programmers. I'm sorry :(

Comment: Of course, I just hit a snag: Both your solutions are returning different results. Unfortunately, I don't know which answer is correct at this juncture, until I get around to serializing the graph for inspection.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm so dumb. There is not enough room in this box to explain how dumb I am. Anyway, different graphs return different results, and should not be compared to determine validity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can naively reverse by just saying "for every node, find all the vertices that have this node in its neighbors list" (the union is necessary in case there are nodes that can be reached, but don't have any neighbors but is unnecessary if for such nodes you have an entry of the form `v -> { }` in your dictionary):

```
var inverse = graph.Keys
                   .Union(
                       graph.Values
                            .SelectMany(v => v)
                            .Distinct()
                   )
                   .ToDictionary(
                       v => v,
                       v => graph.Keys.Where(key => graph[key].Contains(v))
                   );
```

Comment: Since your and Ani's answers have almost identical results, but Ani's answer no longer exists, then you get the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var result = graph.Keys
    .Union(graph.SelectMany(x => x.Value))
    .Distinct()
    .ToDictionary(
        x => x, 
        x => graph.Where(y => y.Value.Contains(x)).Select(y => y.Key).ToList()
    );
```

In conjunction with:

```
foreach (var element in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Key + ": " + string.Join(", ", element.Value));
}
```

Spits out:

> A:
>   B: D
>   C: A
>   D: A, B, C

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I thought I'd provide an alternate take. You can directly call .ToDictionary() on the original dictionary:

```
var inverse = graph.ToDictionary(
    i => i.Key,
    i => graph.Where(j => j.Value.Contains(i.Key))
              .Select(j => j.Key)
              .Distinct()
              .ToList());
```

This selects the current key as the key for the inverse dictionary entry, and then creates a new list from the pairs in the original dictionary by selecting the keys where the edge list value contains the target key and calling .ToList().